# dandelion runtime expression

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack, dandelion

I have in a dandalion datatable a column with a `s:a` tag. In this title attribute i want to call getText with a property of my row variable. How can I do it right?

```
<datatables:table id="annoucementList" data="${listData}" row="announcement">
    <datatables:column>
        <s:a href="%{edit}" title="%{getText('announcement.announcement.list.ankuendigungNr', announcement.ankuendigungNr, announcement.ankuendigungNr)}">
            ${announcement.ankuendigungNr}
        </s:a>
    </datatables:column>
```

Comment: What is this `spring:a` tag?

Comment: Sorry, I mean a struts:a Tag. Definition is org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.AnchorTag

Comment: Do you have errors? What's wrong with the code above?

Comment: There are no errors, but in line 3 the values announcement.ankuendigungNr will not be evaluated. If I surround this with ${}, I will receive an error, that no runtime expressions are allowed.

Comment: What about line 4?

Comment: Line 4 works correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the variable if it's in the `valueStack` using OGNL expression. To access scoped variables use `#attr`. It searches in all scopes.

```
<s:a href="%{edit}" title="%{getText('announcement.announcement.list.ankuendigungNr', #attr.announcement.ankuendigungNr, #attr.announcement.ankuendigungNr)}">
            ${announcement.ankuendigungNr}
</s:a>
```